# How to add to INSERT INTO PRIMARY KEY AND FOREIGN KEY

Tags: java, sql

So i have two tables: locations and employees i want `locations_id` to be the same in `employees.locations_id`, I am trying to make it all in one statement
the erros is this **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO employees(employees_id, locations_id) VALUES('e1598','')' at line 1**

```
String sql = " INSERT INTO locations( locations_id , username, password, id, type_of_id, first_name, last_name, phone, email, date_of_birth, address, sex ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
 **Error here --->**           + "INSERT INTO employees(employees_id,locations_id) VALUES (?,SELECT locations_id FROM locations INNER JOIN employees ON locations.locations_id =employees.locations_id)";
    try {

       MicroModelGUI micro = new MicroModelGUI();
        PreparedStatement consulta =  micro.connection.prepareStatement(sql);
         consulta.setString(1, tflid.getText());
         consulta.setString(2, tfuser.getText());
         consulta.setString(3, tfpass.getText());
         consulta.setString(4, tfid.getText());
         consulta.setString(5, tftoid.getText());
         consulta.setString(6, tffirst.getText());
         consulta.setString(7,tflast.getText());
         consulta.setString(8,tfphone.getText());
         consulta.setString(9,tfemail.getText());
         consulta.setString(10,tffdn.getText());
         consulta.setString(11,tfaddress.getText());
         consulta.setString(12,tfsex.getText());
         consulta.setString(13,tfeid.getText());
         int resultado = consulta.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Do you want this SQL query to insert a single row or multiple ones?

Comment: in a single row.  i am using a  simple frame to get all data from employeess and locations with textfield

Comment: Always include the exact error (meaning the full error or exception text) in any question you ask please. Otherwise people are mostly guessing what the problem is. Apart from that, the second insert statement doesn't make much sense to me. Perhaps describe what you are trying to accomplish as well.

Comment: yes i want  to do it just in one Swing screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` here:

```
INSERT INTO employees (employees_id, locations_id)
SELECT ?, l.locations_id
FROM locations l
INNER JOIN employees e ON l.locations_id = e.locations_id;
```

To the `?` placeholder you would bind a value from your Java code.  Note that while your version of SQL might support putting a scalar subquery into a `VALUES` clause, it is likely that your exact version would cause an error, as it would return more than one row.